# Dynamically attach directive name to html tag using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

Is it possible to attach directive name to HTML tag by using user defined function which is defined in controller.

Assume directive name is test-val 
    
    
In controller 
    $scope.test = function() {
     do something // attach directive name to html div [id=attch]
    }

On trigger of a function test() div should attach directive name. Is this is possible?

Comment: Couldn't this be done with a DOM element with the directive on it with an ng-if statement? ng-if doesn't insert the element until the expression results to true.

Comment: Can i get example if possible?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bGZDszqI4yOBbuFv2DzN?p=preview